# D7 - Whitespace before printed fields

Tags: theming, entities

How to get rid of the whitespace in printed fields?

Here's my source code in node.tpl:

```
<div class="banner" style="background-image:url('<?php print render($content['page_banner']); ?>');">
```

And here's the result (whitespace before http://)

```
<div class="banner" style="background-image:url('  http://localhost/files/styles/1180x300/public/banners/test.jpg?itok=5LPh1ZdQ');">
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried just adding trim ? Like :  <div class="banner" style="background-image:url('<?php print trim(render($content['page_banner'])); ?>');

Comment: Excellent ! I'm glad that helped.    :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a trim() ? Like :

```
<div class="banner" style="background-image:url('<?php print trim(render($content['page_banner'])); ?>');
```

It should just do the trick...

Beyond that, whatever is generating the `$content['page_banner']` content is probably adding the unnecessary spaces.